# Parse.com create stripe card token in cloud code (main.js)

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, token, stripe-payments, parse-cloud-code

I am looking to create stripe token in parse cloud code..

I dont want to create token in client side HTML page. My complete web application is in HTML + Javascript so dont want to expose my Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_xxxxxxx');

Because of this reason interest to define function in cloud code.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("addCreditCard", function(request, response) {
    var token;
    var group;

    var Stripe = require('https://js.stripe.com/v2/');
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_xxxxxxxxx');

    Stripe.card.createToken({
        number : request.params.number,
        cvc : request.params.cvc,
        exp_month : request.params.month,
        exp_year : request.params.year
    }, {
        sucsess: function(result) { response.success("Ok"); },
        error : function(error) { response.error(error); }
    });
});
```

Here parse cloud unable to call **var Stripe = require('https://js.stripe.com/v2/');**

If so many place suggested use parse cloud stripe module 
    **var Stripe = require('stripe');
    var STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = 'sk_test_xxxxxxxxxx';**

But here the function `Stripe.card.createToken` is not define

Comment: try using Stripe.tokens.create instead of Stripe.cart.createToken? https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object

Comment: No such method createToken i am refering https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Stripe.Tokens.html

Comment: Why don't you want to expose your publishable key? It's totally safe as explained here: https://support.stripe.com/questions/difference-between-secret-key-and-publishable-key  Doing what you plan will require the card details to reach your server and you would have to be PCI compliant on your own which is a lot of work

Comment: I want to minimize the client side things and plan most of the things in cloud function.. Because client side source code is exposed

Answer (score 1):

Finally my research is over and I got the solution:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method : 'POST',
    url : 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens',
    headers : {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    },
    body : {
        "card[number]" : request.params.number,
        "card[exp_month]" : request.params.month,
        "card[exp_year]" : request.params.year,
        "card[cvc]" : request.params.cvc
    },
    success : function(httpResponse) {
        token = httpResponse.data.id; // Its token which required for create payment/charge
    },
    error : function(httpResponse) {
        // Error
    }
})
```

The above code can be used in any cloud function which are written in main.js

Comment: As someone else said, this will require you to be pci compliant. This goes far beyond everything being behind SSL

Comment: In anycase if we are taking payment information at our page we required PCI compliant certificate and SSL.. Otherwise we have to redirect on payment gateway page because those are PCI compliant..

Comment: Not actually totally correct. If you were using stripe as intended, sensitive credit card details are never passed to the server, so never leave the client, therefore negate the need for pci compliance