# Convert Stripe cURL code to Parse.Cloud.httpRequests

Tags: rest, curl, parse-platform, stripe-payments, parse-cloud-code

How would you convert the following code into Parse REST http request?

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges \
-u {PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY}: \
-H "Stripe-Account: {CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}" \
-d amount=1000 \
-d currency=aud \
-d source={TOKEN}
```

I've attempted the following but am receiving 401 authorization errors:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("payMerchantDirect", function(request, response){
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://" + {PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY} + ':@' + "api.stripe.com/v1" + "/charges/",
  headers: {
        "Stripe-Account": request.params.{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}
  },
  body: {
        'amount': 1000,
        'currency': "aud",
        'source': request.params.{TOKEN}
  },
  success: function(httpResponse) {
            response.success(httpResponse.text);
            },
  error: function(httpResponse) {
            response.error('Request failed with response code ' +     httpResponse.status);
            }
  });
});
```

I've triple checked the Stripe keys and IDs used, but alas still not working. Is it correct to place the -u cURL variable in the url?

Cheers,
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Another issue was that by adding parameters to the URL resulted in 404 errors.

The solution to this question  ([Parse.com create stripe card token in cloud code (main.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664131/parse-com-create-stripe-card-token-in-cloud-code-main-js)) helped with my question.

Basically you call the -u and -H cURL parameters in the httpRequest 'headers'. Making sure you add the 'Bearer' prefix to the {PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY}.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("payMerchantDirect", function(request, response){
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges",
  headers : {
    'Authorization' : 'Bearer {PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY}',
    'Stripe-Account' : request.params.{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}
  },
  body: {
        'amount': request.params.amount,
        'currency': "aud",
        'source': request.params.sharedCustomerToken
  },
  success: function(httpResponse) {
            response.success(httpResponse.data.id);
            },
            error: function(httpResponse) {
            response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
            }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example where I turned a cURL request into httpRequest:

cURl:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/transfers \
   -u [secret api key]: \
   -d amount=400 \
   -d destination=[account id]\ 
   -d currency=usd
```

httpRequest:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest
(
    {
        method:"POST",
        url: "https://" + STRIPE_SECRET_KEY + ':@' + STRIPE_API_BASE_URL + "/transfers?currency=usd&amount=" + amountOwedProvider.toString() + "&destination=" + recipient_id
    }
)
```

It's not sexy and there is probably a better way using the header/body, but basically I set up the URL, then a ? before all the parameters, and an ampersand (&) between the parameters.

However, it looks like you're just creating a charge. You could use Parse' Stripe module for that.

Also, with connected accounts, you're supposed to either set the account as a destination for the charge, or have very few occurrences of one time transfers from your stripe account to theirs, rather than using a charge. This is for tax purposes.

Comment: Thanks Jake, 
Yes this is for connected account charges. What I'm trying to accomplish is the first method as described in: [link](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#charging-directly)

I have managed to charge a customer and transfer the funds to a destination. However the payments still get handled through the platform account, I would like the connected accounts to manage all that.

Hence the -H variable in my example curl code.